# Generic math equation

Tags: python, math, logic

I have a network (graph) consisting of vertices and arcs as shown below.

[image]

**What I want:**

A want to make a set of random walks through the network from day 1 to day m such that all vertices are visited in at least one random walk in the set of random walks.

I do this in a while loop.

**Problem:**

The smallest possible instance (network) consist of three types of vertices (day, evening and night) in a period of 28 days.

Which result in the while loop running for ever. This is due to the fact that a random walk will most likely end in night case, and the probability for a random walk consisting vertex (n-2) is (1/3^28 = 0,00000000000000131%).

The starting point in a random walk, is that the next vertex/arc is chosen uniformly random among the possible vertices/arcs. In my network this would result in the following probabilities:

```
[(1/3, 1/3, 1/3), (0, 1/2, 1/2), (0, 0, 1)]
#Equivalent to
[(33, 33, 33), (0, 50, 50), (0, 0, 100)]
#[(day),(evening),(night)]
```

Where each tuple represents with which probabilities the next vertex most be chosen when the last vertex chosen was respectively day, evening and night.

**Solution:**

The solution I came up with was to change the probabilities [(33, 33, 33), (0, 50, 50), (0, 0, 100)] to fx [(80, 15, 5), (0, 80, 20), (0, 0, 100)].

I would due that based on the number of arcs from each type of vertex to each type of vertex.

```
#list1
[[27,27,27], [0,27,27], [0,0,27]]
#list2
[(80, 15, 5), (0, 80, 20), (0, 0, 100)]
```

To sum up:

The first vector in the matrix (in list1) represents the number of edges from a vertex type 1 to respectively vertex type 1, type 2 and type 3. Similarly, vector 2 represents the number of edges from vertex type 2 to respectively vector type 1, type 2 and type 3 and similarly with vector 3.

list2 represents with which probability the next vertex in a random walk will be chosen for respectively vertex type 1, type 2 and type 3, when the last chosen vertex was respectively type 1, type 2 and type 3.

**Help needed:**

I want to obtain something similar to [(80, 15, 5), (0, 80, 20), (0, 0, 100)] based on [[27,27,27], [0,27,27], [0,0,27]].

How can I mathematically do this?

(It should not necessarily give the exact same values but in the same size ratio as in list2 (since they are just based on logic))

I think it can somehow be expressed mathematically in a generic way, such that it works for more complex networks with not necessarily the same graph structure.

**Bonus info:**
Another example, where I want to find a set of probabilities could be the following, which is the second least complicated extension [[27,27,27,27],[0,27,27,0],[0,0,27,0],[27,27,27,27]].

**Update:**
I was tipped, that I maybe could simulate it, but can't figure out how to do this in practice. Which probabilities should I then use? and how can I use this simulation to obtain the best possible percentages?

Comment: I'm searching a method to obtain something similar to: [(80, 15, 5), (0, 80, 20), (0, 0, 100)] (not the necessarily the exact same numbers but as close as possible) only based on [[27,27,27], [0,27,27], [0,0,27]]. Yes, the above example is the smallest and most simple possible case, which are iteratively extended to larger and more complex cases. It is used as a part of a larger implementation of a problem.

Comment: One example of a simple extension of list1 could be [[27,27,27,27],[0,27,27,0],[0,0,27,0],[27,27,27,27]]. But eventually the structure will not follow the same pattern.

Comment: Hi JohanC, I changed my question completly, such that it hopefully makes more sense now. I would really appreciate if you could read it once again and give feedback, if something is still unclear or details missing.

Comment: The only way to arrive at `n`, `n-1` and `n-2` with equal probability seems to be with all weights zero except for going straight (which would get 100%). If you have weights such as `[(80, 15, 5), (0, 80, 20), (0, 0, 100)]` in only a few days almost all paths lead to 'night'.

Comment: Do you have any suggestions to derive better probabilities to ensure the traversal of vertex `n`, `n-1` and `n-2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is somewhat ill-defined. Only with assigning 100% to one and 0 to the rest, the probabilities can stay the same. Depending on how much you deviate from 100%, the result will deviate more.

The probabilities for each day can be calculated as a matrix multiplication.
For the example case, for the first day this multiplication looks like:

```
  [1/3]   [ 0.80 0.15 0.05 ]
  [1/3] · [ 0    0.80 0.20 ]
  [1/3]   [ 0    0    1    ]
```

Continuing multiplying with the same matrix gets the probabilities for the subsequent day.

The code below plots the evolution of the probabilities. To simplify the number of parameters a bit, the code starts with assigning a probability of 80% to one, and then 80% of the other 20% to the second.

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import ticker
import numpy as np

N = 29
x0 = np.array([1, 1, 1])
x0 = x0 / x0.sum() # starting probabilites, suppose all equal; make them sum to 1
a = 80 / 100
b = (1 - a) * a
c = a
m = np.array([(a, b, 1-a-b), (0, c, 1-c), (0, 0, 1)])
# m = m / m.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True)  # normalize such that rows sum to 1

x = np.zeros((N, len(x0)))
x[0,:] = x0
for i in range(N-1):
    x[i+1, :] = np.matmul(x[i], m)

labels = ['day', 'evening', 'night']
ind = np.arange(N)
for i, lab in enumerate(labels):
    plt.plot(ind, x[:,i], label=lab, marker='.', ls='-')
plt.xticks(ind)
plt.xlabel('day')
plt.gca().yaxis.set_major_formatter(ticker.PercentFormatter(1))
plt.title(f'Highest weight for going to next day: {a*100:.1f} %')
plt.legend()
```

Plot with highest probability 80%:
[image: plot for 80%]

Plot with highest probability 99%:
[image: plot for 99%]

Only with 100%, the probabilities stay constant to 33.3% each.

Here is what the other example would look like with the given weights:

```
x0 = np.array([1, 1, 1, 1])
x0 = x0 / x0.sum()  # all values sum to 1
m = np.array([[27, 27, 27, 27], [0, 27, 27, 0], [0, 0, 27, 0], [27, 27, 27, 27]])
m = m / m.sum(axis=1, keepdims=True)  # normalize such that rows sum to 1
labels = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']
```

As the probabilities for A and D are always equal in this case, the curves coincide.
[image: example with 4 curves]

Again, the optimal solution is which gives weight 0 to the nodes that already have too many incoming arrows:

```
[[50, 0, 0, 50], [0, 100, 0, 0], [0, 0, 100, 0], [50, 0, 0, 50]]
```